# Двумерный массив, как лучше реализовать доступ к элементам?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Есть двумерный массив, прямоугольный массив a[i][j]. Требуется просуммировать значения по СТОЛБЦАМ.  По строкам ничего сложного нет, а по столбцам не получается.

Добавил псевдокод.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {   
   int sum = 0;                             
   for(int j = 2; j < a[i].size(); j++) {   
      sum +=a[i][j];
}
}
```

Comment: "не получается" - ?? Что тут может не получаться? `i` и `j` поменять?

Comment: А как вы делали по строкам? Вот **точно так же** и по столбцам - с заменой индексов.

Comment: Конец дня, не могу сообразить ((

Comment: И почему вдруг цикл по `j` начинается с `2`, а не с `0`?

Comment: опечатался.  начинается с 0

Comment: Все, вопрос закрыт. Всем спасибо, голова совсем не варила ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы матрица была квадратной, то решение было бы гораздо меньше..

*Простой пример для понимания:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector <vector <int>> a = {
        {1, 0, 3, 5, 3},
        {2, 0, 4, 6, 0}, 
        {4, 1, 6, 0, 2},
        {5, 0, 2, 1, 0}
    };

    // Проходим по рядах 
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {   
        int sum = 0;                             
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++) {   
            sum +=a[i][j];
        }
        cout << "Row sum = " << sum << endl;
    }  

    // Теперь считаем в каждой колонке
    for(int j = 0; j < a[0].size(); j++) {   
        int sum = 0;                             
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {   
             sum +=a[i][j];
        }
        cout << "Column sum = " << sum << endl;
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
Row sum = 12
Row sum = 12
Row sum = 13
Row sum = 8
Column sum = 12
Column sum = 1
Column sum = 15
Column sum = 12
Column sum = 5
```

Comment: Сдаётся мне, этот код только с квадратными массивами работает...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да.. Исправил. Должно работать!

Comment: Ага, вижу, должно :)